# Splitting the code(commands/events) in different files

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm always coding in only one file that called index.js like main scripting file.
So, i seen people splitting the code to different files.
For example, music bot. It has commands play, pause, loop etc, how i can split it to different files and connect it to index.js?

Comment: Have you checked [Node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) on that - and if so, are there any specific questions?

Comment: Look up ES6 imports and common JS require (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import, https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/)